# No data exists for the row/column in vb.net using sql serverce 2008

Tags: vb.net

```
   Try
                If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Open()
                End If
                scmd.CommandText = "select bal, billamnt  from bills "
                Dim drr2 As SqlCeDataReader
                drr2 = scmd.ExecuteReader
                If drr2.Read Then
                    bal = dta(drr("bal"))
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

i am getting error in drr2  the error is :No data exists for the row/column while drr1 is executing

please sove it in vb.net

Comment: Show why you are certain drr has data just because drr2 has data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
        Try
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
            scmd.CommandText = "select bal, billamnt  from bills"
            Dim drr2 As SqlCeDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader
            While drr2.Read()
                bal = dta(drr2("bal"))
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

If you have more than one row returned you will need to handle that.